# New to Apache: what exacty should my conf file contain for a basic forward proxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, mod-proxy

I was hoping to get some help setting up Apache as a forward proxy, primarily just to know how it's done and for learning. I've found countless examples that look a lot like this:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy>
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

But I'm not sure what to do with that information. What happens in the rest of the conf file? Do I just append it to the bottom and activate all the proxy modules? And if so, why isn't working when I try it with Firefox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This config should work, you'll probably want to drop any sites/virtual hosts that it's actually trying to serve up if it's going to be a dedicated proxy.

Check what settings the Apache config has for `Listen` directives - the proxy will need to be using one of those ports (this will be either in the main apache conf file, or a separate ports.conf file).

Along those same lines, what url did you place in the firefox proxy configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I'm just using all the default apache settings, I don't know much about it yet so I don't really know much of anything about it to be honest -_-

I'm listening on port 81 because something else is using 80 (still trying to figure out what), and that's what I have Firefox set to. I have it set to allow all just until I get it working.

I'm trying to use DynDNS, which I imagine could be the problem, but I've tried both the URL it gives me and my actual port and neither works, unless my basic knowledge of how the internet works, that should be fine.

Comment: @HankJDoomstorm What happens if you just browse to the URL that you're putting in the proxy setting?

Comment: With the server running it shows me the HTML file in the htdocs directory.